# If $f,g: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are measurable, show $\{f>g\}=\{x \in D \mid f(x) > g(x)\}$ is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $f,g: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are measurable, show $\{f>g\}=\{x \in D \mid f(x) > g(x)\}$ is measurable.

I'm new to this whole meausure theory thing and am gonna need some help...

$f,g$ are both measurable, so given any open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}$, both $f^{-1}(U)$ and $g^{-1}(U)$ are measurable. Therefore, it'd be nice if the image of $\{f>g\}=\{x \in D \mid f(x) > g(x)\}$ was open, because then I could just take the preimage and boom, it must be a measurable set, ha, but this must not be it. Can anyone lend some advice?

Comment: Maybe you can try to show for example that $f-g$ is measurable ? so you will have $\lbrace f > g \rbrace = \lbrace f-g > 0 \rbrace = (f-g)^{-1}([0,+\infty[ ) $

Comment: Try considering $\cup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \{f(x) > q\} \cap \{g(x) < q\}$. (This is a standard strategy. Each of these sets is measurable, so, since the measurable sets are a $\sigma$-algebra, what can you conclude?)

Comment: @pierre21 doesn't this come from the fact that the set of measurable functions is an algebra?

Comment: @Chris brilliant! Since the measurable sets are a $\sigma$-algebra, they are closed under countable unions and intersections, and the union of intersections that you constructed is equivalent to {$f>g$}. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it come from that fact